Positive divisors on a projective surface
Let $M$ be an (projective) algebraic (nonsingular) surface and $L$ a line bundle on $M$.
In p.472 of Griffiths-Harris, the formula $$\chi(L)=\chi(\mathcal{O}_M)+\frac{L^2-LK}{2} $$
is proved. The proof begins with: Choose a divisor $D$ on $M$ sufficiently positive so that both $|L|$ and $|L+D|$ contain smooth, irreducible divisors.
I can't understand how to take $D$. In fact this question has been asked in: Quick question: sufficiently positive divisor. But I have some questions about the answer. Since the answer given in the link is quite old, I decided to post a new question.

How can we write $L=A-B$ with $A,B$ very ample? I know that we can always write $L=L_+-L_-$ where both $L_+$ and $L_-$ are effective. For projective manifolds are "effective divisors" and "very ample divisors" equivalent?

How Bertini's theorem implies that a generic element of a linear system is irreducible? In Griffiths-Harris Bertini's theorem only states that a generic element is smooth.

For a projective manifold are "positive divisors" and "ample divisors" equivalent?



All these questions are answered in standard textbooks (e.g., in Hartshorne).


First write $L$ as a difference of effective divisors: $L = L_+ - L_-$. Now use that for any effective divisor $E$ and any ample divisor $A$, $D = E + mA$ is ample for $m \gg 0$ (you should be able to find this in the first volume of Lazarsfeld's Positivity...). Effective divisors are not at all the same as very ample divisors on almost any variety; effective is very nearly the weakest notion of positivity commonly studied, while very ampleness is the strongest.

In a typical Bertini argument, you will be able to say that the generic element is also connected. Smooth, connected things are irreducible (i.e., to be both reducible and connected implies the existence of a singular point at which the irreducible components meet).

Positive is a vague term. As I stated above, very ampleness is the strongest form of positivity, while effectiveness is nearly the weakest (the weakest, psuedoeffectiveness, just means "is a limit of effective divisors," limit meaning in the Euclidean topology on $\operatorname{Pic}(X)\otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb R$).


